# Ansible task condition is always false referencing dict member

Tags: ansible

I have a dict variable defined as follows (confirmed with debug of the var)

```
"mydict": {
        "architecture_name": "un", 
        "architecture_number": 0, 
        "distribution_name": "rh7", 
        "distribution_number": 0, 
        "product": 1
 }
```

and ansible task as follows:

```
- name: "Convert distro name to number"
    set_fact:
      cacheable: yes
      mydict: "{{ mydict | combine({ 'distribution_number': 6}) }}"
    when: "{{ mydict['distribution_name'] == 'rh7' }}"
```

but the task always fails, saying the condition result was false.  Why?

Comment: Ansible should be warning you about your `when` condition: you never include Jinja `{{...}}` template markers in a `when` condition because you're already implicitly inside a Jinja template context. This isn't your problem, but it's something you should fix.

Comment: It would help if you could post a runnable playbook that reproduces this problem. If I put your task and data into a playbook (like [this](https://gist.github.com/larsks/89b960c20b3622c852fd9498e5eaab8b)), it seems to run without a problem, which suggests your data is maybe other than you think it is.

Comment: @larsks you were correct - I did not format my next task properly, which did NOT cause any syntax error in Ansible but messed up execution of the prior task.  Once I fixed that the lines below, the code above worked as expected.

Answer (score -2):

After having quick look it seems like problem is in following code, not in the when condition.

```
set_fact:
      cacheable: yes
      mydict: "{{ mydict | combine({ 'distribution_number': 6}) }}"
```

May be you can refer correct manipulation [documentation with set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html)

If i run this code without set_fact then its perfectly working. for eg:

you can run example A)

```
---
- name: Dictionary playbook example
  hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    - mydict: {
                "architecture_name": "un", 
                "architecture_number": 0,  
                "distribution_name": "rh7", 
                "distribution_number": 0,  
                "product": 1
               }
  tasks:
    - name: Display the Dictionary 
      debug: var=mydict
      when: "{{ mydict['distribution_name'] == 'rh8' }}"
```

Above example A will not print dict in logs, but following example B) will print it

Example B)

```
---
- name: Dictionary playbook example
  hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    - mydict: {
                "architecture_name": "un", 
                "architecture_number": 0,  
                "distribution_name": "rh7", 
                "distribution_number": 0,  
                "product": 1
               }
  tasks:
    - name: Display the Dictionary 
      debug: var=mydict
      when: "{{ mydict['distribution_name'] == 'rh7' }}"
```

Comment: The only difference between your A and B example that I can see is 'rh8' vs 'rh7'.  I don't understand, how does that connect to set_fact?

Comment: As well, ansible reports (with -vvv) that task was skipped because condition was false, so I assume it must be the when clause

Comment: @TSG  you did not get me, as i wrote it does not connect to set_fact and mentioned clearly that you need to properly read documentation of set_fact .  in my example you see difference is rh8 and rh7 that is because i want to show you "when" condition is working,  nothing else.  In your orginal code because of wrong code in set_fact you are seeing this side affect of when condition. I am not sure why you gave -1 on this post as i wanted to help you out but got -1